# T-SQL Dynamically Changing Field Being Updated Using an IF Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, sql-update, case

We have a denomination table that stores records per unique identifier key and per denomination, so any given unique identifier key can have up to 13 rows indicating the denomination breakdown for up to 7 different transaction types within that row. I could easily copy and paste my query below (which is working great) 7 times, each with a different SET and WHERE clause combination, but that would look messy and very long.

The query:

```
    UPDATE #RecycleCashDenomsClone
    SET startBal =
        CASE
            WHEN B.DenomType = '1.00' THEN A.d_01
            WHEN B.DenomType = '2.00' THEN A.d_02
            WHEN B.DenomType = '5.00' THEN A.d_05
            WHEN B.DenomType = '10.00' THEN A.d_10
            WHEN B.DenomType = '20.00' THEN A.d_20
            WHEN B.DenomType = '50.00' THEN A.d_50
            WHEN B.DenomType = '100.00' THEN A.d_100
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.01' THEN A.c_01
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.05' THEN A.c_05
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.10' THEN A.c_10
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.25' THEN A.c_25
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.50' THEN A.c_50
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C1.00' THEN A.c_100
        END 
    FROM #VaultTotals A INNER JOIN #RecycleCashDenomsClone B ON A.importKey = B.importKey
    WHERE A.identifier = 'D0510'
```

What I would love to do... Set an if statement that changes @updatedField and @whereField (varchars) to the 7 different combinations and pass them into the query as follows:

```
    UPDATE #RecycleCashDenomsClone
    SET @updatedField =
        CASE
            WHEN B.DenomType = '1.00' THEN A.d_01
            WHEN B.DenomType = '2.00' THEN A.d_02
            WHEN B.DenomType = '5.00' THEN A.d_05
            WHEN B.DenomType = '10.00' THEN A.d_10
            WHEN B.DenomType = '20.00' THEN A.d_20
            WHEN B.DenomType = '50.00' THEN A.d_50
            WHEN B.DenomType = '100.00' THEN A.d_100
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.01' THEN A.c_01
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.05' THEN A.c_05
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.10' THEN A.c_10
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.25' THEN A.c_25
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.50' THEN A.c_50
            WHEN B.DenomType = 'C1.00' THEN A.c_100
        END 
    FROM #VaultTotals A INNER JOIN #RecycleCashDenomsClone B ON A.importKey = B.importKey
    WHERE A.identifier = @whereField
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, no error message, it just doesn't update the fields. I'd like to avoid Dynamic SQL if possible, and like I mentioned above, I'd like to avoid copy pasting this query 7 times with a different field and where clause.

P.S. I tested this by making the two variables varchar(10) and setting them to strings. ex./

```
DECLARE @updatedField VARCHAR(10) = 'startBal'
DECLARE @whereField VARCHAR(10) = 'D0510'
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i don't see how you can avoid dynamic sql here.

Comment: `UPDATE`, like `SELECT`, can set the value of a variable. That is what your code does. It isn't a case of "this doesn't work, no error message," but a result that you weren't expecting or checking for. It's also a case of _optimistic programming_: I want it to do what I want, e.g. `set ColB = @ColName @Operator @Constant` where it should _know_ that the first two variable values should be reinterpreted as source code, but not the third.

Comment: Is the `case` expression identical for all of the updated fields? If so, you could calculate the value in a CTE or subquery and then handle each field with `... set Field1 = case when @UpdatedField = 'Field1' then cte.CaseValue else Field1 end, Field2 = case when @UpdateField = 'Field2' then cte.CaseValue else Field2 end, ...`. Or, if needed, the inner `case` may also reference `@whereField`, e.g. `... set Field1 = case when @UpdatedField = 'Field1' and A.Identifier = X.D0510 then cte.CaseValue else Field1 end, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution, but an idea to help you.

I do not like this solution because the case is the same for all conditions and it updates all fields every time.

```
UPDATE B
    SET startBal = CASE WHEN @updatedField = 'startBal' THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '1.00' THEN A.d_01
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '2.00' THEN A.d_02
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '5.00' THEN A.d_05
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '10.00' THEN A.d_10
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '20.00' THEN A.d_20
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '50.00' THEN A.d_50
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '100.00' THEN A.d_100
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.01' THEN A.c_01
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.05' THEN A.c_05
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.10' THEN A.c_10
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.25' THEN A.c_25
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.50' THEN A.c_50
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C1.00' THEN A.c_100
                END 
            ELSE startBal END
            ,startBal1 = CASE WHEN @updatedField = 'startBal1' THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '1.00' THEN A.d_01
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '2.00' THEN A.d_02
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '5.00' THEN A.d_05
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '10.00' THEN A.d_10
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '20.00' THEN A.d_20
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '50.00' THEN A.d_50
                    WHEN B.DenomType = '100.00' THEN A.d_100
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.01' THEN A.c_01
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.05' THEN A.c_05
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.10' THEN A.c_10
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.25' THEN A.c_25
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C0.50' THEN A.c_50
                    WHEN B.DenomType = 'C1.00' THEN A.c_100
                END 
            ELSE startBal1 END
    FROM #VaultTotals A INNER JOIN #RecycleCashDenomsClone B ON A.importKey = B.importKey
    WHERE A.identifier = @whereField
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I was trying to avoid, there are 7 different options for the @updatedField i will need and by doing it this way, it's almost exactly the same length as just copy and pasting it with the hard coded options.

Comment: Try to use sp_executesql (Transact-SQL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql